# Extending PHP Class in Namespace

Tags: php, class, namespaces

I have a PHP class-- a generic ODBC database interface. While the methods will never change (because it uses PDO), the connection string will. To avoid having the user pass in an entire connection string manually or specify an ODBC driver to be placed into a connection string, I extend the class and create a SQL Server specific version.

**Generic PDO ODBC Driver**

```
class PDO_ODBC implements DBDriver{
    private $driver;
    private $connection_string;

    public function connect(){
        if(!$this->driver || !$this->connection_string){
            throw new \Exception("Invalid connection string or database driver.");
        }
    }
}
```

**SQL Server Specific Version**

```
class PDO_ODBC_SQL_Server extends PDO_ODBC{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->driver = 'SQL Server';
        $this->connection_string = 'odbc:Driver={[Driver]};Server=[Host];Database=[DBName];Uid=[Username];Pwd=[Password]';
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I create a new `PDO_ODBC_SQL_Server` object and call `connect()`, the exception is thrown because `$this->driver` and `$this->connection_string` doesn't exist. But how can this be? If I use `print_r`, I *see* both of those properties. One thing to note is that `print_r` *also* shows the namespace of the class for all properties *except* the driver and connection string, as shown here: http://pastebin.com/qh40eDpa. In fact, there are *separate* variables of connection string and driver under the namespace.

How can I fix this and prevent the exception from being thrown, while still being able to use a similar design pattern by extending the base ODBC class? If not, then the alternative is to allow for the developer to pass in a driver and connection string...

*Note, I've omitted most of the private variables in the code sample above for brevity. Both of these classes are located in separate files and are under the namespace `Lib\Database`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the class properties `protected` or make getters and setters if you want to keep them private. Private properties can only be accessed from the class in which they are declared, not derived classes.

```
class PDO_ODBC implements DBDriver{
    protected $driver;
    protected $connection_string;

    public function connect(){
        if(!$this->driver || !$this->connection_string){
            throw new \Exception("Invalid connection string or database driver.");
        }
    }
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php#language.oop5.visibility-members